# cp: fts_open: No such file or directory / Why?

Tags: macos, bash, cp

I have following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This script will copy all JPG files inside directory '~/temp/merged':";

pwd;

read -r -p "Please confirm, that you want to copy all JPG files [y/N]" response

case $response in
    [yY][eE][sS]|[yY]) 
        find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' f ;

        mkdir -p ~/temp/merged;

        do 
          echo "$f"
          cp "$f" ~/temp/merged/$orig_f
        done 
        ;;
        *)
        ;;
 esac
```

It gives me errors like this in the end of correct execution:

cp: fts_open: No such file or directory

Why? Please help understand.

Comment: Directory traversals over NFS shares can trigger this, especially if the `rdirplus` NFS mount option is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say precisely what your problem is, but there are several issues.

The main problem I see is with this line:
`cp "$f" ~/temp/merged/$orig_f`

Before executing cp, the shell is looking for a variable `orig_f` (that does not exist).

Underscores are valid characters in variable names, i.e. `variable_a="value"`. So if you are trying to prefix or append a variable with an underscore, you need to do as such: `${variable}_a`.

The other issue is with quoting. Say `orig_f` does exist, the contents could contain spaces that expand and cause issues. So be sure to quote any variables that could expand as such.

You could greatly simplify your script by using:

```
mkdir -p ~/temp/merged
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -print -exec cp {} ~/temp/merged \;
```

If you must use a while loop, do this instead:

```
mkdir -p ~/temp/merged
while IFS= read -d '' f; do 
    echo "$f"
    cp "$f" ~/temp/merged
done < <(find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -print0)
```